# Formrecognizer preview: Train model error Payload too large

Tags: machine-learning, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'm trying to train a model in the formrecognizer preview using the test console (western europe) provided by azure. But i get an error code 413 Payload Too Large. The error message is: Unable to process dataset. Size of dataset exceeds size limit (4.00MB).

I've provided a SAS-Storage-Url pointing to a blob container. This blob container contains 5 png-files. Each with a size between 2.7 and 3.1 MB and with a content-type of application/png.

From the documentation i know that the file size must be smaller than 4 Mb. 
Is the size of the complete dataset (sum of all trainig files) restricted to four Megabytes?

Answer (score 1):

Form Recognizer v1 supports a training set which must be less than 4 megabytes (MB) total. The Form Recognizer v1 APIs are sync APIs and have a time limit on the processing time, hence the limits. Form Recognizer v2.0 (preview) is an async API and enabling training on large data sets. Please use the v2.0 (preview) API.

Comment: I'm still hitting this issue one year later.  4 Mb total for typical commercial scanned PDF's is far too small.  The only other recourse is to downscale the scanned documents from 300 DPS which can be complex without tools.  Is there a location where a request can be made to increase this amount 4Mb limit?

Answer (score 0):

Further detail: **try the V2 API or later.**

It isn't possible to "solve" this problem other than to shrink the training documents. A process for shrinking them manually rather than using code is below:

- PDFEscape (has a free trial, excellent tool)

  - Export all images from page
- Irfanview - batch operations, resize images by percent, save to PDF
- PDFEscape select all PDF versions of individual page images, right-click in Windows explorer and PDFEscape-merge.  Reorder if necessary, then save the new PDF